# Misunderstanding of Reputation on Meta Description?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta, per-site-meta

Allow me to quote the Tour of `meta.stackexchange.com`

> Meta Stack Exchange account functions like an account on any other Stack Exchange Q&A site: your **reputation score goes up** when others vote up your questions and answers, and you earn badges for your activity here.

I don't know if I am reading this right or not, but it states that reputation *will* go up within the `meta.` of StackEchange. While, on `webmasters.`, `maths.`, and other sites, it says it is not going to change. It is there for discussions, bugs, and feature issues.

And allow me to quote what it says in the FAQs.

> **Voting is different on meta.**
>
> Like normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta allows members to vote on questions and answers. For most posts, votes reflect the perceived usefulness: well-written, well-reasoned, well-researched posts tend to get more attention and more upvotes. Highly-voted and frequently-linked posts may become part of the community-curated FAQ or codified as part of the site’s Help pages.

Should it be reworded that this only happens on this meta only and not the other site's meta? Or does it mean that it does happen om all meta sites?

I think this could cause some slight confusion like it has for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allow me to disambiguate.

Meta Stack Exchange is a site unto itself; it may have the name "Meta" in the title, but it is now its own standalone site, much like Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and others.

The per-community metas, such as Meta Stack Overflow, Meta Server Fault, and others, will use the reputation of their parent site to determine your reputation on that meta.

> I don't know if I am reading this right or not, but it states that reputation will go up within the meta. of StackEchange.

Your reputation will only be affected on Meta Stack Exchange.  Other per-meta sites do *not* experience a change in reputation (either good or bad) on a vote.  This also means that bounties cannot be attached to questions on a per-site meta.

Comment: Aye. That does make sense. It just seems that it can be confusing also by the ideas of the meta design and the way it is worded.

Comment: So do we need a meta.META to discuss META?